# looking up the actual string with value using MS ACCESS query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Let me take you through other way.... 
I am trying to achieve through MS Access SQL Query.

**tblPatient**

```
patient_Name    Events1     Event2  Event3
A                1            2      3
B                3
```

**tblEvents**

```
Patient_Name    Events  Event_Name
A                1       Vomiting
A                2       Ashtma
A                3       Fever
A                4       Cough
B                1       Viral
B                3       Nasuhe
```

I want the result as shown below by joining the tables..
**output**

```
Patient_Name    Event 1 Event_Name  Event2  Event_Name  Event3  Event_Name
A                1      Vomiting     2      Ashtma   3       Fever
B                3      Nasuhe
```

the below query I used for the above output, but its giving some error type Mismatch expression.

```
    SELECT eot.patient_Name, 
       eot.Events1, 
       tb1.Event_Name, 
       eot.Event2, 
       tb2.Event_Name, 
       eot.Event3, 
       tb3.Event_Name
FROM (TblPatients AS eot LEFT JOIN tblEvents AS tb1 ON eot.patient_Name = tb1.patient_Name AND eot.Events1 = tb1.Events) 
      LEFT JOIN tblEvents AS tb2 ON eot.patient_Name = tb2.patient_Name AND eot.Events2 = tb2.Events 
      LEFT JOIN tblEvents AS tb3 ON eot.patient_Name = tb3.patient_Name AND eot.Events3 = tb3.Events;
```

how can I go forward with this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, your example is not clear. Why do you have a separate "Patient Table" that omits some of the entries in the "Events Table"? Specifically, why does it not include event 4 for patient A and event 1 for patient B? Please [edit] your question to clarify what purpose this "Patient Table" is actually supposed to serve.

Comment: Patient table do not have the Event name but it has the events like 1 , 2, 3 .but those Events name are available in Events Table. Now the goal is get those relavent (something) like vlookuping up the event (ex 1 of patient A) from events table and should return those event name of that subject as Vomiting... like that 2 and 3. hope you got the clarity?

Purpose of this patient table is to look on their event name as a ownerview in rows w.r.t to unique subjects as statement in the above output tables?

event 4 is not there in Patient table of any patients, so it does need to lookup the table.

Comment: @gord, edited the orginal post, hope the example is clear